# Reduce spacing after heading of List of Figures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

I have some issue with my LaTeX document.

It uses `scrbook` class and I don't like the chapter spacings in the List of Figures. 
For the actual content, the spacing is nice, but in the LOF, I'd like to reduce the `space` after the `\listoffigures` command.

For the table of contents I've included 
`\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1.2cm}` 
which reduces the space after the heading. Is there something similar I can do for the LOF?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, draft=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[notlot,nottoc,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}        
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures   

\chapter{Bla}

\begin{figure}[htb]
 \makebox[\textwidth][l]{
    \includegraphics*[width=0.65\textwidth]{someImage.png}
 }\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:lable}
\end{figure} 

\section{1.1}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The spacing of concern is highlighted by the red rectangle.

Would be great, if somebody could help me out and let me know, how I can just reduce this specific spacing in the List of Figures.

EDIT:
I've just realized that my problem is related to the usage of `tocbibind`. When I use that specific package, the answer tohecz `\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip -1.2cm}` does not work. I've adjusted the MWE accordingly.
[image]

Comment: `\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip -1.2cm}` ?

Comment: How about `\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace{0ex minus .1ex}}`?

Comment: @tohecz: this was my first thought, nevertheless, it ain't working for the LOF and the spacing remains the same.

Comment: @hpesoj626: this does not work either, moreover, it also changes all chapter headings throughout the entire document. So basically, it is precisly what I didn't want to achieve ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example works on my machine are reduces the space:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, draft=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[notlot,nottoc,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1.2cm}
\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip -1.2cm}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures   

\chapter{Bla}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Caption}
\label{fig:lable}
\end{figure} 

\section{1.1}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Listfiles output:

> ```
>  *File List*
>  scrbook.cls    2011/01/25 v3.08 KOMA-Script document class (book)
> scrkbase.sty    2011/01/25 v3.08 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
> ics and keyval usage)
>  scrbase.sty    2011/01/25 v3.08 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
> asics and keyval usage)
>   keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
> scrlfile.sty    2010/11/05 v3.08 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
> tocbasic.sty    2010/10/01 v3.07a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
> scrsize11pt.clo    2011/01/25 v3.08 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
> typearea.sty    2011/01/25 v3.08 KOMA-Script package (type area)
>   lipsum.sty    2005/01/26 v1.0 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
> tocbibind.sty    2010/10/13 v1.5k extra ToC listings
> titlesec.sty    2007/08/12 v2.8 Sectioning titles
> graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
> graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>     trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
> graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
>   pdftex.def    2011/01/28 v0.05d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
>  caption.sty    2010/01/09 v3.1m Customizing captions (AR)
> caption3.sty    2010/01/14 v3.1m caption3 kernel (AR)
> supp-pdf.mkii
> pdftexcmds.sty    2010/04/01 v0.9 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
> infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
> ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
>  ltxcmds.sty    2010/04/26 v1.7 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
> epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
>   grfext.sty    2007/09/30 v1.0 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
> kvoptions.sty    2010/02/22 v3.7 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
> kvsetkeys.sty    2010/03/01 v1.9 Key value parser (HO)
> etexcmds.sty    2010/01/28 v1.3 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
> epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
>  ***********
> ```

I would like to remark that I consider such modification as a misfortunate one. Lists of Contents are just chapters as any other ones and the spacing should be consistent.

As well, your construction for figures using `\makebox` seems to me unnecessary, you can just do this I think

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering % if you wish
  \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{image.png}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{fig:ff}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've found the reason why it doesn't work for me. When I add `\usepackage{tocloft}` to the MWE as well as your solution, the spacing is not as intended. Dou you have any idea why?

Comment: @FloatingPointZilch If you are loading `tocloft`, you can simply say `\setlength\cftafterloftitleskip{0pt}` (instead of `0pt` use the desired length).

Comment: JFYI: The recent KOMA-Script version is v3.11b, 2012/07/29.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Thanks ever so much! Works like a charm...